# What is the more elegant way to sample a random number until it's not present in the set?

Tags: python, loops

I am wondering what is the more elegant (if this word is appropriate in this case) way to keep generating a random number until it's not in the set of used values. The first option is repetitive in that we have the same line for `random type` both inside and outside the while-loop.

The second one, however, needs to add a conditional statement to break out of the loop. I understand that this particular case is trivial and both versions work, but which looks more Python/elegant in your opinion?

```
def orchestrator(image = None):
    used_values = set()

    for _ in range(7):
        toss = np.random.random()

        if toss >= 0.5:
            random_type = np.random.randint(1,7,1)[0]
            while random_type in used_values:
                random_type = np.random.randint(1,7,1)[0]
            used_values.add(random_type)
            print(random_type)
```

```
def orchestrator(image = None):
    used_values = set()

    for _ in range(7):
        toss = np.random.random()

        if toss >= 0.5:
            while True:
                random_type = np.random.randint(1,7,1)[0]
                if random_type not in used_values:
                    break
            used_values.add(random_type)
            print(random_type)
```

Comment: If you only want to generate numbers from 1 to 7, uniquely and without replacement, why not just `random.shuffle(range(1,7))` or whatever?

Comment: Note: If your question is not about generating non-repeating random numbers, but about whether a mid-loop `break` is preferable to repeating code, I'd vote for `break` being DRY and increasing readability, some others would say `break` is always an abomination — it's a perfect example of an opinion question, and would be closed before you can say "The Art of Computer Programming".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you have to do some remembering anyway, it's easier to go the opposite way, remember *unused* things. This solves several problems: you never need to repeat the random generation, and a list is sufficient so you don't get the memory overhead of a set.

```
from random import shuffle
unused_values = list(range(7))
shuffle(unused_values)
```

then whenever you need a new non-repeating random number,

```
random_type = unused_values.pop()
```